# Car Faraday cage

Tags: charge, faraday-cage

I have been reading about the Faraday cages in the last couple of days.

My learning raised another questions about charge accumulation on a car frame.

Air friction can raise the amount of charge on the frame surface acting like a Faraday cage. That charge can evacuate by giving a shock when someone touches it.

However, if no one touches for a very long time after it accumulated charges, will it remain there so anyone who touches it will finally unload the car charge by getting a shock or will it discharge in another way?

Comment: Black rubber tires have too low resisance to ground for that to be an issue.

Comment: All imbalances charge will eventually equalize since no perfect insulators exist (unless maybe floating in a vacuum). It's just a matter of how long. Everything also becomes a conductor at high enough voltage so if you keep accumulating charge faster than it can dissipate, eventually it will arc somewhere to equalize.

Comment: oh so it can go through tire? so any insulation over a period of time allows charge to leak? I yes you can post it as an answer, it definitely enlightens me to something I didn't know!!

Comment: Tires use carbon black. That's why they are black. Carbon = conductive

Comment: No.  Any accumulated charge will bleed/leak off to the atmosphere or through a high-resistive path path to ground.  In this context, high resistance means in the tens or hundreds of mega-ohms region.  Anything less than that will just allow any charge to bleed off faster.

Comment: for the car, will it leak most likely through the air or probably the tire since they offer less resistance? Thx again for your time, marked your answer

Comment: A tractor knocked over a power pole and the conductor was touching the cab which was then at the potential of the cable. At this point the driver was still ok, however, while getting out the driver held onto the tractor frame and, when his foot hit the ground he was electrocuted... So tires are not always good conductors...

Comment: @SolarMike heh, yeah You can bleed off 90% of a billion volts from a lightning bolt but that remainder can still be high enough to be dangerous

Comment: oh yeah I know that story, but with a car haha. But yeah not right away, but my point was like, giving a million year, the tire would end up evacuating that charges

Comment: I saw it happen once, but we persuaded the driver to stay still untill the cable was moved. The fun of contracting for 15 hours a day...

Comment: @Cherry Well, not as long as the power line was in contact and functional, continuing to keep the car charged for those million years. But I think you get the idea

Comment: haha yeah I meant once the line is removed ;)

Comment: see this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/477807/are-esd-safe-tools-necessary-with-proper-setup/477811#477811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All charge imbalances will eventually equalize since no perfect insulators exist (unless maybe floating in a vacuum). It's just a matter of how long. Everything also becomes a conductor at high enough voltage so if you keep accumulating charge faster than it can dissipate, eventually the potential difference between it and the next nearest thing in the universe will become high enough to arc to it in order to equalize, whether it be air or vacuum, if something doesn't touch it first.